Google reCaptcha essentials vs standard vs enterprise
Does anyone know how can I deploy the google reCaptcha standard.
I already coded and deployed recaptcha essensials and looked into enterpise solution. the latter does not have secret key and completely different from the first one. Here is it says how complicated it is:
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/reCAPTCHA-Enterprise/recaptcha-enterprise-is-just-crazy-hard/m-p/703561
How can I choose and deploy recaptcha standard and find sample codes. Does it have secret key on server side validation.
I found this talking about standard plan is introduced recenlty.
https://www.inclind.com/news/google-recaptcha-price-change
I asked this quesiton on community:
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/reCAPTCHA-Enterprise/How-to-choose-standard-plan-for-recaptcha/m-p/788351#M195

Here is my answer, please add your comment and verify it.
First you should upgrade your keys if you are on non enterprise tiers from "UPGRADE KEY"

Once you have done, you have done, you will have "KEY DETAILS". After you go with either with standard or enterprise.
Standard vs. Enterprise APIs,

Standard:
Site Key: You include a site key for invisible reCAPTCHA.
rendering captcha in frontend
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

and
in backend to verify post a request (where it creates assessment)



 https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify


on the otherhand for enterprise:
not like rendering a widget as in standard
on backend you post
POST
https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/assessments?key=YOUR_API_KEY

